# place JS result in php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

The script below converts any image to base 64, I am trying to place the converted string in a php variable before I insert it to my database.

**my JS**

```
function uploadFile() {

  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

    var FR= new FileReader();

    FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      document.getElementById("img").src       = e.target.result;
      document.getElementById("b64").innerHTML = e.target.result;
    }); 

    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
  }

}

document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile);
```

**my html**

```
<input id="inp" type='file'>
<p id="b64"></p>
<img id="img" height="150">
```

What I am trying to achieve is place the result that i'm displaying now in the p tag with id="b64 in a php variable $varImage.

```
.innerHTML = e.target.result;
```

I read online that i can only be done with AJAX, but i am not sure how to use ajax if its the case ? or can it be done differently ?

Comment: You could use a library like jQuery, see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for the description and exampes of how to use ajax.

Comment: @user1915746 should i use ajax ? or can it be done differently ?

Comment: You could also use a `<form>` to submit the base64 from client to server. Or you upload the file to the server (also using  `<form>`) and calculate the base64 string on server side.

Comment: you dont need to use ajax, make one form, and in that make one textbox, now put your result in that textbox via js code like element.getElementById.value = e.target.result;, and submit the form to action you want to send.

Comment: @DHRUVGUPTA can you tell me how to do it without ajax ? you mean show the data in a hidden text input ? and post it to server ?

Comment: make it a form and then submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Ajax, you can place the generated value into hidden input value and simply send the form, so the PHP script processing form will get it in $_POST['b64'] variable.

HTML

```
    <input id="inp" type='file'>
    <input type="hidden" id="b64" value="">
    <img id="img" height="150">
```

JS

```
      function readFile() {

      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

        var FR= new FileReader();

        FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
          document.getElementById("img").src       = e.target.result;
          document.getElementById("b64").value = e.target.result;
        }); 

        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AJAX is one of the simplest ways for uploading, here's a quick how-to showing the simplest you could do.

First, include jQuery by putting this in the `<head>` of your html(use the cdn below or a local download of it)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now, back to your (javascript) code. Let's say the base64 string is in the variable `result`. We can send a `POST` request to the PHP server (in this sample to the file `upload.php`) with the result in the request body.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "upload.php",
  data: { img: result }
});
```

Now, in `upload.php`, this is all you need:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['img'])) {
        $varImage = $_POST['img'];
    } else {
        print 'No image sent!';
    }
?>
```

And you can now use `$varImage` for whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since the js script is executed on the client computer and the php is executed on the server (host) computer. You have to send the data from your js to your php.
You can use [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) of course but is not the only solution. If your are not confortable with jquery an you prefere native js there is another [solution](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

There is an example of an ajax request :

```
$.post("mysite/create",
                    {  "data": JSON.stringify({'id': id})},
                    function (data, status) {
                        console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

                    });
            });
```

And there is an example of native js XmlHttpRequest :

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "mysite/create", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

The last solution is to use a form:

```
<form method="post" action="mysite/create">
<input name="data">
</form>
```

Either way you need to go through that step in order to save your data to your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send variable from .js to .php without `ajax`.

js

```
$.ajax({
   url: "",
   data: {
      name: "value"
   }
})
```

php

```
$data = htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]); // return "value";
```